# MVC: Download file and return model from same action

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc

I have to download file and return with the file some data in a model.

I was research it, but I couldn't find any result to do this. For now I can say "It is not possible", but maybe some of you can answer on my question. 
I need something like:

```
...return Json(new {data:"some string", File("some.zip")});
```

Also, I am using an angularJS in the client side. So to connect with the server I am using `$http` statement and as responseType I have "arraybuffer".

Comment: You want to download a file AND a model ? or a file IN a model ? The JSON you provided is not a valid one, as there is no key for the File("some.zip") value

Comment: file and model, or file in model. For me is importatnt to get data from server by one response.

Answer (score 1):

You could base64 encode your file, and send it as a JSON property:

```
Byte[] bytes = File.ReadAllBytes("path");
String file = Convert.ToBase64String(bytes);

// JObject from Newtonsoft Json.net library
var json = new JObject
{
    {"data","some data" },
    {"file", file },
    // You could add some file properties as well :
    {"filesize": 54836 },
    {"filetype": "image/jpeg"},
    {"filename": "profile.jpg"},
};

return Json(json, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

Then, in your angular / javascript code, you can refer to [this article](http://blog.danguer.com/2011/10/24/base64-binary-decoding-in-javascript/) (untested) to convert back your encoded file.

Comment: article not found :(

Comment: Link fixed. you can always google for angular decode base64 file